# Rollback Azure SQL DB in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

this is the situation, we are planned to do next product release in two weeks, everything is on road as planned. this release have lot of DB changes, as we are using .Net EF, all DB changes are maintained in migration files. All going good.

But, after release, if something went wrong in code we can easily rollback the release to previous release build in pipeline. what about the DB changes, once the migration files are executed, there will some new columns, new tables, some columns are altered in DB. how to rollback this. one fine solution is we can take backup of DB before initiate the release, if anything went wrong, old DB can be restored. but that is not fair. we like to go with some professional way.

so, what are ways or steps we need to follow to Rollback the DB in EF.

Answer (score 0):

```
Script-Migration StartingMigrationThatYouWantToRemove LatesMigrationThatYouWantToKeep -i
```

Run this command in package manager console to generate the revert script for your migration. When you decide to undo the db changes, just run the generated script. Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#script-migration)

Comment: you mean we need to run this command in package manager console? or in some other way..

Comment: Correct @saravanan049. I've edited my answer.